# Trouble with #defined identifier in c++

Tags: c++

I"m writing a program that ,extensively, depends on an identifier:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS 12
```

The parameter is used in a number of projects (in one solution).
The problem is that i have two modes: first NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS is 12 and second NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS equals to 16.

Is there a way to change the value of the parameter during run-time? if not is there any work-around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, not at runtime. `#define` directives are interpreted by the compiler and cannot be changed once the program has been compiled.

Comment: Runtime - not with a macro. Why can't you just use a variable? Is this for an array? In which case you can't pick the size at runtime, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @Nbr44 the compiler doesn't even get to see the `#defines`, it just sees a bunch of `12`s.

Comment: @juanchopanza I will shamefully admit I took an abusive shortcut.

Comment: @Nbr44 *#define directives are interpreted by the compiler* **NO** by the pre-processor. The compiler only sees the output of that.

Comment: Neither the C standard nor the C++ standard require you to have a preprocessor. The first footnote to C++11 section 2.2 merely says that "implementations must behave as if these separate phases occur, although in practice different phases might be folded together", so the standard has no issue at all with the compiler doing the preprocessing.

Answer (score 6):

`#define` provides constants to the pre-processor.  They are not available at runtime or directly to the compiler itself.

You would need to use a runtime variable if you want this value to be changed at runtime.  The best way to define this depends a great deal on the structure of your program.

Answer (score 2):

As others already have said you can't change this value during runtime, because preprocessor changes NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS with 12 / 16 before compilation.

You can start with changing NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS to global const. It of course won't be pretty solution either but you can take it from there (maybe some object managing it, I can't really tell more without knowing about specifics of your program).

Answer (score 1):

The C++ macros are used in compilation time, if you need something that you can change in runtime, you can create a global or a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

In case of an integer parameter on which a lot of code depends critically, changing at run-time is best achieved by changing from one implementation to another, ideally using a template:

in code.h:

```
#include <stdexcept>
template<int NumberOfElements>
struct ComplicatedCode
{
  void run(int, char**);
};

void RunComplicatedCode(int NumberOfElements, int argc, char**argc)
{
   switch(NumberOfElements) {
   case 12: ComplicatedCode<12>::run(argc,argv); break;
   case 16: ComplicatedCode<16>::run(argc,argv); break;
   default: throw std::invalid_argument();
   }
}
```

in code.cc:

```
#include "code.h"
template<int NumberOfElements>
void ComplicatedCode::run(int argc, char**argv)
{
  /* implementation details, depending on NumberOfElements */
}

template void ComplicatedCode<12>::run(int, char**);  // instantination for 12
template void ComplicatedCode<16>::run(int, char**);  // instantination for 16
```